# Map fills with color when changing CRS, how to properly change map CRS

Tags: qgis

I'm trying to change a map of the middle east from EPSG 4326 to EPSG 3394, but after the transformation the entire map gets filled with the same color as the province layer, with some borders disappearing. Am I missing something obvious?

[image: Before transformation]

[image: After transformation]

Comment: EPSG:3394 is a variant of lambert confomal conic, if your original data is worldwide, features near to the south pole suffers near-infinite deformation. Maybe cropping the data to your desired map extension is a good idea to start with.

Comment: @Babel I've just been using the natural Earth data

Comment: @Javier JC that sounds like it might be what's wrong with it, how can I crop the data to just be the middle east?

Comment: @pestoman you can do this with the QGIS processing toolbox, search "Extract/clip by extent" under vector tools

Answer (score 2):

EPSG:3394 is a variant of lambert confomal conic, if your original data is worldwide, features near to the south pole suffers near-infinite deformation. You should crop the data to your desired map extension.

You can do it from "Processing"->"Toolbox"->"clip by extent"

You can also select the features on your desired region and save those as a separate layer, also from the Toolbox with "Save Selected Features"